# Why does IntelliJ Idea add "_war_exploded" to context path of deployment?

Tags: intellij-idea, web-deployment

I have a Java EE web project named test and I use Wildfly as server.

When I use Eclipse the URL in the eclipse's integrated browser is : `localhost:8080/test`.

But when I use IntelliJ the URL in Chrome is: `localhost:8080/test_war_exploded`.

Why IntelliJ idea add this: `_war_exploded`?

Comment: You can configure the deployment, look that:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-web-application-deployment.html

Comment: @DilneiCunha The probleme is that I don't understand what does the deployment do!

Comment: Can I just run the app normally like eclipse without this "deployment"?

Comment: for web application you have two types of deployment .war ou exploded basically you deploy an archive (.war) or by deploy folder, change the type to Web Application: Archive if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

In `pom.xml` add tag `finalName`, example:

```
<build>
    <!-- this tag -->
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

then edit launch url.

OR for GlassFish:

In Edit Configuration change URL("Server") and context root ("Deployment").
[image: Edit Configuration]

[image: Server]

[image: Deployment]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to edit Application context. Please find the menu route:
Run > Debug > Edit Configurations...> in Deployment edit/delete Application context

Answer (score 1):

What actually worked for me:

0. Stop the Server if it is Running;
1. In the Menu Bar Above Press -> Run;
2. Debug;
3. Edit Configurations;
4. Select your server (Tomcat or etc.);
5. Deployment;
6. In the Application Context Bar: delete (packageName)_war_exploded/
7. Press Apply and Debug

Hope it worked!